# Bamboo to Build Specific SVN Revision

Tags: svn, continuous-integration, bamboo

Imagine there's a project in [Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/) with two build plans: *Staging Deployment* (SD) and *Production Deployment* (PD). Building *SD* checks out latest sources, builds them and deploys a web site to a staging server. Currently, *PD* does all the same, namely deploys the latest version of a web site to a production server. Clearly, this is not very good: I want to be able to deploy the same exact version of a web site that was previously deployed on a staging server, not the latest one.

To illustrate: suppose we're at `r101` in SVN repo. Clicking "*Build SD*" will deploy a web site version, say, `2.1.0.101` to staging server. Now we commit a breaking change and end up at `r102`. Now I want to deploy to a production server. If I hit "*Build PD*", Bamboo will happily check out `r102` and build it, resulting in version `2.1.0.102` being deployed to a production server.

What I want it to do, however, is to build and deploy a version which was previously built in an *SD* plan (that is, `2.1.0.101`).

Of course I can make *SD* plan to tag latest-successful build as `tags/builds/latest`, but I would rather have Bamboo itself handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is tagging each successful staging deployment with a well-known tag (like, `/tags/project-latest') and then building production build from that tag.

Answer (score 5):

From your build command, you can specify the revision to use with the option `custom.svn.revision.number`. So, it'll be something like `-Dcustom.svn.revision.number=101` into the *PD* plan's configuration.

**Note:** You need Bamboo v1.1 or later for this.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to enter the revision number manually? Is there a way to "promote" a build from the SD plan and get the PD plan to just find out the specific SVN revision? (maybe when SD plan does a build, log the SVN revision in a build-specific log or manifest file)

Comment: I'm hoping this is no longer the case -- this should be trivial to do from the UI. Will keep looking :-)

Comment: Missing information about how exactly to specify this. The built-in "Source Code Checkout" task doesn't provide a way to specify the custom revision number, and there's no way to specify `-D` parameters there. You may wish to edit your answer to elaborate.